# S is dense equivalency statement

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove $S$ is dense in a metric space iff the intersection of $S$ with any open ball in $X$ is non-empty. I have show the first part assuming S is dense in X but I am having trouble going the other way around. I am struggling to construct a sequence in S that goes to an arbitrary $x \in X$. Any help as to how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take balls with centre $x$.

Comment: What is the definition of dense you're working with?

Comment: S is dense in X if for any x in X, there is a sequence in S that converges to x. Would it work if I took $x_i$ in S intersect B(x,1/n).

Comment: @user153009 yes, that will work.